# How to create authentication ticket from asp.net for sharepoint 2010?

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have an asp.net website and sharepoint 2010 web application running on two different sub domains of the same main domain. e.g. asp.net website domain is aspnet.company.com and sharepoint website domain is sp.company.com.

I have a login page on asp.net website, where I want to issue an authentication ticket for sp web application so that the user will not have to log in again when navigating from one to another.

I tried doing this using the same <machinekey /> element, I have indicated the name="company.com" in <forms /> element.

Still no luck. Though I know that was possible this way for sp2007.

I guess this does not work because now sp2010 uses claims.

Can please someone say how it can be done?

Thanks.

Tengiz

Comment: Excellent question. Have you found an answer ? I'm looking for exactly the same thing. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I found a workaround which worked for me. Added the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem.

Please read my answers and explanations on another forum (because that was the first place I gave an answer on this):
[Authentication cookie sharing between Share Point 2010 and ASP.NET 4.](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/755d21a7-a54d-4257-aabe-900ab199d1b8/)

Cheers!
Tengiz